# Why is it defaulting to "uncategorized" even after I select a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization

I have created a custom taxonomy and configured it to work like a category. The taxonomy shows up fine on the admin, but when I create a post, it is then placed in the default `uncategorized` category. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestion?

My function is:

```
function register_taxonomy_test() {

$labels = array( 
    'name' => _x( 'test', 'test' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'test', 'test' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search test', 'test' ),
    'popular_items' => _x( 'Popular test', 'test' ),
    'all_items' => _x( 'All test', 'test' ),
    'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent test', 'test' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent test:', 'test' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit test', 'test' ),
    'update_item' => _x( 'Update test', 'test' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New test', 'test' ),
    'new_item_name' => _x( 'New test', 'test' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate test with commas', 'test' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove test', 'test' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from the most used test', 'test' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'test', 'test' ),
);

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => false,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,

    'rewrite' => array( 
        'slug' => 'little', 
        'with_front' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true
    ),
    'query_var' => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'test', array('post'), $args );
};
```

EDIT:

@Charles - yes I have added the code below sorry/. forgot to mention it here.

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_test' );
```

@OTTO - it shows up in the uncategorized "category" even after I make sure I have checked on a custom taxomony I created

EDIT #2

Ok so I decided to go with regular categories and not custom taxonomies. For any one interested why a new post with custom taxomony defaults to un-categorized, is because it is linked to the post type which is "post". So you must also enable a custom post type "register_post_type()" that is linked to your custom taxonomies that will act as categories.

Comment: First you have at the end of your code a Semicolon for whatever reason(delete it!), secondly you don't have any action hook? Add following code on next line at the end: `add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_test', 0 );`

Comment: Custom Taxonomies don't replace categories, they are separate. Do you mean that it shows up in the uncategorized "category", or as uncategorized in your custom taxonomy?

Comment: thanks for the reply! it shows up in the uncategorized "category" even after I make sure I have checked on a custom taxomony I created

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I decided to go with regular categories and not custom taxonomies. For any one interested why a new post with custom taxomony defaults to un-categorized, is because it is linked to the post type which is "post". So you must also enable a custom post type "register_post_type()" that is linked to your custom taxonomies that will act as categories.